# how can access images from sqlite db and displaying those images in gallery in android using cursor adapter?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have implemented this in a code but its giving an error that cannot convert BLOB into long. Here I have a piece of code that I have implemented but I'm getting an error:

```
Cursor cur = myDbHelper.getImages();  //images has been recieved in cursor

ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, cur);

lst.setAdapter(adapter);



/* ImageAdapter Class*/
public ImageAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup arg2) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.residentgallery, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())  
        {  
           do  
           {  
               System.out.println("byte array");
               byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("images"));  
               ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);  
               Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);  
               iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
               System.out.println("Imageview");
           }  
           while(cursor.moveToNext());  
        }

        return view;
    }
```

After running this code I'm getting this error:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error: Unable to convert BLOB to long`

I have saved images in sqlite in BLOB datatype.
Guys, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch **images/photos from standard gallery**:

```
String[] selectFields = new String[] {
    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    // other fields you interested in
    };

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,selectFields ,where,null,orderBy);
if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    int col_id = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        int imageID = cursor.getInt(col_id);
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(imageID));
        InputStream istr = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

---

If you want to store and fetch later **your app's private images**:

It's good practice to store images as separate files and insert into database only filename and other meta-data related to this image. You can always select filename from db and then read your image from file.

Also, it isn't good to store many large files in internal memory. May be you can use sdcard?

Comment: so Its not possible to fetch multiple images from db in gallery...right

Comment: Do you want to **fetch images from standard gallery**? or your own images?

Comment: May be you can do this, but it's bad way.. prefer files, don't store images in BLOB